# Pause animation for fixed duration in Windows phone 8

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8

I have a simple animation that i did using blend that moves a TextBlock to the left till it vanishes from the screen

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="dtitle">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="-523.831" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="titleblock" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I have one button 'Start' that should play the animation for about 0.25 secs and then pause it. So if the user presses the button, the TextBlock will move a tiny bit to the left and then stop. Is there something like

```
dtitle.Resume()
//wait 0.25 secs
dtitle.Pause()
```

or maybe

`dtitle.PlayForSeconds(0.25)`

The user should be able to use the UI within this period.

Comment: Any reason you can't just split it out into two separate animations?

Comment: you can use dispatchertimer for o.25 sec. and then start it again.